# How to copy data in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am using appache airflow in my project. In this user can connect their data base with our project and copy their table to our data base .

So I am able to establish a connection using the following lines

```
    import json 
    
    from airflow.models.connection import Connection 
    
    c = Connection(
         conn_id='some_conn',
         conn_type='mysql',
         description='connection description',
         host='myhost.com',
         login='myname',
         schema = 'myschema'
         password='mypassword',
         extra=json.dumps(dict(this_param='some val', that_param='other val*')),
     )
    print(f"AIRFLOW_CONN_{c.conn_id.upper()}='{c.get_uri()}'")
    
    hook = MySqlHook(c.conn_id)

   result = hook.get_records(f'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = {c.schema};')
```

Now I am able to get the table names associated with the connected data base ....

How to copy data from this connected data base to our data base .... Please help me with some hints on this

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what databases you want to copy data between.

A straightforward approach could be outlined as the following steps.

1. Grab the records from Database A.
2. Insert the records to Database B.

You would create a custom operator that would perform those steps in order. There might even be operators already created that fulfill these functions. I would advice you to take a look in the [Airflow Github](https://github.com/apache/airflow) first.

Please note that this approach is not suitable for large datasets because the data is stored in memory during the task execution. You can also write to disk but that route then depends on the machine that the Airflow worker runs on.

If the database lives in the same cluster/server then a simple SQL script would work. A [HiveOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py), for example, would be sufficient to move data with some `INSERT INTO` sql commands.